# How to type "function space" in Latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, unicode-math, function

In learning basic function space ,I met some special symbols. They are not \mathcal,\mathscr.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I'v  tried to search special greek symbols or math symbols but failed.

Comment: They do seem to be `\mathcal` just in some other font.  Note that there is no set look for mathematical symbols, it all depends on the font being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are capital `S`, `D` and `E` in the font QT Boulevard. Compile with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{QTBoulevard}
\begin{document}

SDE

\end{document}
```